# Is there a way to dynamically populate a value field in Flask-WTF form?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a `create` and an `update`
 notes views.
Each view has the same form to create/update a note.

I was wondering **on a good way to render the value of my content only in the update view but not in the create view.**

Here what I have today :

```html
<div class="field">
    {{ form.title.label }}
    {% if request.endpoint == 'notes.update' %}
        <div class="control">
            {{ form.title(class="input", value=note.title) }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="control">
            {{ form.title(class="input"}}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

I use a condition on the endpoint to do what I want but I don't think it's a good way to do this.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate the form in your endpoint.

```
form = NotesForm(request.form)
form.populate_obj(note)
```

There is a solution for dictionaries, too.

```
form = NotesForm(request.form, data={'title':'Untitled Note'})
```